# Easy way to find if I already answered

Tags: support

Is there an easy way to find if I already answered to a specific question? This extrapolation of the Stackoverflow format to a code golf site sometimes seems very inadequate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for

```
user:me inquestion:???
```

Where `???` is the question ID you'll find in the URL of the question. This works on all SEs.

Answer (score 3):

Using search works well and is useful for a number of things (e.g., finding all answers in language X to a specific question), but since golf is all about minimizing strokes, here's another way.

1. First, make sure you've enabled [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166/170332). You can do this by going to your [Preferences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/) and checking *Enable keyboard shortcuts*.
2. Check that you're not focusing any text area or input field.
3. Press <kbd>A</kbd>. This will focus the answer field if you haven't answered the question yet, but display a popup asking *Are you sure you want to add another answer?* if you have.

Naturally, this doesn't work for closed/locked questions.

If keyboard shortcuts aren't available for some reason, you can still scroll to the bottom of the page to check is there is a *Post Your Answer* button or an *Add Another Answer* button. In most browsers, you achieve this by pressing <kbd>End</kbd>.